# How to Share Text from an RTF File Swift 3

Tags: swift

I'm not even sure if this is possible, but here it goes anyway:

I have RTF files within my app, which are used to populate text views. I want my users to be able to share the text within those files, not the files themselves.

This is the code I'm currently using to share the files:

```
@IBAction func shareRecipeTxtBtn(_ sender: Any) {

    let grabIngredientTxt = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "bananaPancakes_ing", withExtension: "rtf")
    let grabDirectionTxt = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "bananaPancakes_dir", withExtension: "rtf")

    let txtToShare = [grabIngredientTxt, grabDirectionTxt]

    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: txtToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view 

    activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityType.postToFacebook, UIActivityType.postToTwitter]

    self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

The attached screenshot is the result of the code above, but it's not ideal.

[What users currently see when they attempt to share a file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiMoL.jpg)

Comment: You are pointing your app to files, not their contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't you grab the text being displayed from the text views

```
let txtToShare = [textView1.text, textView2.text]
```

or

```
let txtToShare = ["\(textView1.text)\n\(textView2.text)]
```